# Nested route for 2 views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple website that has a menu made up of Items and customers can order food by paying with their credit card.

I want to spilt the menu into 'lunch' and 'dinner', I have already created a menu_type field for each item but i'm unsure how to create the views without breaking the nested routes.

I basically need 2 new views for the lunch menu and dinner menu and then add them to the routes.

#### Controller

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end
  def lunch_menu
    @items = Item.where(:menu_type => 'Lunch')
  end
  def dinner_menu
    @items = Item.where(:menu_type => 'Dinner')
  end
end
```

#### Model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :is_live, :price_in_pence, :menu_type, :title

  has_many :order_items

end
```

#### Routes

```
resources :items, :path => "menu", only: [ :index ] do
    resource :basket, only: [ :create, :destroy ]
end
```

Comment: Why have I been down marked for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the actions in your controller so just create the views associated with them and then change your routes as follows:

```
resources :items, :path => "menu", only: [ :index ] do
    resource :basket, only: [ :create, :destroy ]
    collection do
       get "lunch_menu"
       get "dinner_menu"
    end
end
```

This will give you routes of `/items/lunch_menu` and `/items/dinner_menu`

Answer (score 1):

You could just do...

```
def index
  Time.now.hour > 4 ? dinner_menu : lunch_menu
end
```

Which is to say you still use the one route but adjust items selected based on some external criteria.  I'm suggesting time of day but you might have a start_menu action that sets a session variable for whether it's the lunch or dinner menu you're currently working with.

Comment: Ah that's a nice idea but I want people to be able to order from either menu at anytime of the day :)

Comment: Well, that's absolutely fine.  They would choose which menu to look at, right?  (Show Lunch | Show Dinner) so that becomes your session variable sesson[:menu_type] 

You could then do `@items = Item.where(:menu_type => session[:menu_type])`

Comment: Great option but the answer above is what I was look for. Thanks

Comment: No problem glad you found an answer!